# Tweening opacity of text box with Scrollmagic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I am attempting to make a psuedo-parallax site. I am using the Scrollmagic jquery plugin. My background animations are working fine, but I am having issues with the first text box (living in the grey bar). I have it set to start at opacity:1 and tween to opacity:0. When I load the page, the div container already seems to have the opacity set to .5. What am I doing wrong? I've tried adjusting the duration in TweenMax.to to .5 and I've seen no difference how .text-background is tweening.

The codepen is available here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vExZPR

Thank you.

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="parallax1">
                <div style="background-image: url('img/evcbg1.jpg');">
                    <div id="parallax1_content">
                        <div class="text-background"><h1>We offer a full line of EPA approved enclosed combustors that meet the ever-changing<br>requirements of today’s regulation-filled oil and gas industry.</h1></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h2>Are you in compliance with the latest EPA tank emission regulations?</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="parallax2">
                <div style="background-image: url('img/clouds.jpg')"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h2>Are you in compliance with the latest EPA tank emission regulations?</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="parallax3">
                <div style="background-image: url('img/clouds.jpg')"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h2>Are you in compliance with the latest EPA tank emission regulations?</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h2>Are you in compliance with the latest EPA tank emission regulations?</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h2>Are you in compliance with the latest EPA tank emission regulations?</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //initialize the controller
                var controller = new ScrollMagic({globalSceneOptions: {triggerHook: "onEnter", duration: $(window).height()*2}});

                //build scenes
                new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#parallax1"})
                    .setTween(TweenMax.to(".text-background", .1, {opacity: "0", ease: Linear.easeNone}))
                    .addTo(controller)
                    .addIndicators({zindex: 1, suffix: "1"});

                new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#parallax1"})
                    .setTween(TweenMax.from("#parallax1 > div", 1, {top: "-80%", ease: Linear.easeNone}))
                    .addTo(controller)
                    .addIndicators({zindex: 1, suffix: "1.BG"});

                new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#parallax2"})
                    .setTween(TweenMax.from("#parallax2 > div", 1, {top: "-80%", ease: Linear.easeNone}))
                    .addTo(controller)
                    .addIndicators({zindex: 999, suffix: "2"});

                new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#parallax3"})
                    .setTween(TweenMax.from("#parallax3 > div", 1, {top: "-80%", ease: Linear.easeNone}))
                    .addTo(controller)
                    .addIndicators({zindex: 999, suffix: "3"});

                // show indicators (requires debug extension)
                    scene.addIndicators();
            });


         </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several notes:
Always make sure your console is clean. If there's stuff there, it probably means you did something wrong.
But not to worry, it also gives you great pointers on how to resolve it.

On your pen, when you look in the console, you find out quickly that there's a problem in line 9, where you call "setIndicators". This is due to the fact, that you forgot to include the ScrollMagic debugging extension.

Then there's another problem in line 27, where it states, that `scene` is undefined.
The variable isn't set and I'm assuming is a C&P error, when copying from one of the ScrollMagic examples.

After resolving these two issues, we can actually see the indicators, except for the starting one, because it's green on green.
Luckily we can change the color.

Once these [issues are resolved](http://codepen.io/janpaepke/pen/xbqYqM) we are set to start working on the actual problem.

Now that we see the scene indicators it should become fairly obvious what's happening.
The scene's `triggerHook` is set to `"onEnter"` with `globalSceneOptions` and is accordingly positioned at the bottom of the viewport.
The `triggerElement` of the scene is set to `"#parallax1"`, which is the main section, which makes its position the top of the page.
So right from the start the trigger is already past the start position of the scene.
And because the duration of the scene is 2 times the window height, this situation (trigger at the bottom, start at the top) results in the scene being exactly at 50% played on load.

**Resolving this is as easy as changing the triggerHook for the scene in question.**
By setting it to `"onLeave"` (or `0`) the scene's triggerHook moves to the top.
Keep in mind that this needs to be done AFTER adding the scene to the controller, because it would be overwritten otherwise, as stated in the docs.

This will leave us at this resolved version: http://codepen.io/janpaepke/pen/WbpMOO

I would recommend to you having a look at the [ScrollMagic scene manipulation example](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/basic/scene_manipulation.html) to get a better idea of what scene parameters will result in which outcome.

For future issues I would also strongly recommend following this guide: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

hope this helps,
J

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! Makes a lot more sense with you explanation, very clear now! Also, thank you for the link to the support guidelines... very much appreciated.

Comment: The two codepen's external files are missing, kindly fix it and update.